# Haskell Evaluation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following block of code:

```
data G = F G G | H Int deriving (Show, Eq)

example :: Int -> G -> G
example 0 (H i) = (H i)
example n (H i) = F (example (n-1) (H i)) (example (n-1) (H i))
example n (F i1 i2) = F (example n i1) (example n i2)
```

When I run `example 0 (F (H 1) (H 2))` , as expected it returns `F (H 1) (H 2)`

When I run `example 1 (F (H 1) (H 2))` , it returns `F (F (H 1) (H 1)) (F (H 2) (H 2))`

This is not what I want. I need to return `F (F (H 1) (H 1)) (H 2)`

What I mean is on the 6th line, `example n (F i1 i2) = F (example n i1) (example n i2)` , I call the recursive function twice. However I wish for `(example n i1)` to evaluate first and update the variable `n` before we evaluate `(example n i2)`

Any help/solutions to this exact problem will be greatly appreciated. I have been trying for hours with zero success.

Comment: How would you use `example` to update `n`? `n` is an `Int`, but `example` returns a `G` value. You can't bind a `G` value to an `Int` variable.

Comment: Is there no way to solve this? Not even by using some helper function?

Comment: I need to first evaluate recursively (example n i1), and then evaluate (example n i2) with n from the end result of the first recursion.

Comment: How do you propose to translate `G` into `Int`? It can be done, but there's several ways, and no unambiguously correct way.

Comment: I do not wish to change my data type for G, that is my only restriction. Would you be able to write me an example using any of the potential methods that achieves what I need? Again, thanks for your help and time.

Comment: *"I wish for (example n i1) to evaluate first and update the variable n."* What value should be used for `n` "after" `(example n i1)`?

Comment: While `example n (F i1 i2) = F (example n i1) i2` seems to match your test case. It is not clear at all, what you want. Your question is missing a specification.

Comment: Write a helper `exampleH :: Int -> G -> (G, Int)` taking `n` as input and returning the "updated" `n` as output in the returned pair.

Comment: What should `example 2 (F (H 1) (H 2))` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you want to use `example` to 'update' `n`. You can't directly do that, however, since `example` returns a `G` value, and `n` is an `Int`.

It seems, then, that you need a function `G -> Int`. The issue is that there's no unambiguously correct way to write that function. In fact, there's infinitely many possible implementations. Here's a sample:

```
evalZero :: G -> Int
evalZero = const 0

evalOne :: G -> Int
evalOne = const 1

evalLeft :: G -> Int
evalLeft (H i) = i
evalLeft (F g _) = evalLeft g

evalRight :: G -> Int
evalRight (H i) = i
evalRight (F _ g) = evalRight g

evalSum :: G -> Int
evalSum (H i) = i
evalSum (F g1 g2) = evalSum g1 + evalSum g2

evalProduct :: G -> Int
evalProduct (H i) = i
evalProduct (F g1 g2) = evalProduct g1 * evalProduct g2

evalPlusOneProduct :: G -> Int
evalPlusOneProduct (H i) = i + 1
evalPlusOneProduct (F g1 g2) = evalPlusOneProduct g1 * evalPlusOneProduct g2

-- etc.
```

As `evalPlusOneProduct` illustrates, you can arbitrarily add or subtract a constant `Int`, or, for that matter, multiply by a constant, or perform more complex arbitrary calculations. Since there's infinitely many integers, there's infinitely many implementations (although, granted, technically, we're constrained by the range of `Int`).

Once you've figured out how to transform `G` into `Int`, you can use that function to calculate a new value `n1` from `n` and the left `G` value.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for spending your time helping me. However, I do not quite understand that solution, or how I may use it / a variant of it to achieve my desired effect.

Comment: My functional programming experience is very limited. However in other languages, one could pass the same pointer for n to achieve my desired solution.

Comment: @Haskell_Adventurer When you call `example n i1` it produces a `G` value. Use a `G -> Int` function to evaluate that `G` to an `Int`. The resulting `Int` is your `n1`. Now invoke `example n1 i2`.

Comment: I think I get it now. So we pass the output of `example n i1` into some function of type `G -> Int` that produces an `Int`, say n1, which we then use for `example n1 i2`. But wouldn't this mean having to recurse `example n i` twice? And by twice I mean once for when we calculate `example n i1` and once for when we use it to calculate the `Int`.

Comment: @Haskell_Adventurer No, but you may need a `let` binding. http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

Comment: The thing that confuses me the most about this problem is that it is recursive but it does not have a definite base case because of line 5. Is there anything that I could read on recursive functions that use recursion twice like in the example above, similar to line 5, that being `example n (F i1 i2) = F (example n i1)(example n i2)` ?

Comment: Like with a more "normal" recursive problem we know that when a base case is reached, a value is returned. However for this problem when a base case is reached it does not necessarily mean that the overall recursion is over and a value may be returned later.

Comment: @Haskell_Adventurer The way that you've written the function `example 0 (H i)` is a base case.

Comment: Actually, as the output of the examples I've given suggests, the function does not return a value exactly when a base case is met. We have to wait for all subrecursions to end. And that I find very confusing and difficult to work with.

Comment: Thanks to your idea and support, I was able to solve my problem (a more complex variant of the example given). Thank you so much.